# CDK not hooking up API Gateway v2 default authorizer correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway-v2

I'm playing around with CDK (java, 2.128.0) and the API Gateway v2 and have a very simple

```
HttpApi.Builder.create(this, "HttpApi").apiName("HttpApi").defaultIntegration(integration).defaultAuthorizer(authorizer).build();
```

The integration works without the authorizer but when I add it, I get {"message":"Unauthorized"} and no debug in the CloudWatch that is ever hit. When looking at the Lambda console API Gateway integration for the authorizer, there is an error

The API with ID  doesn’t include a route with path /* having an integration arn:aws:lambda:::function:AuthorizerLambda.

I recall it "just worked" when it was in alpha(?). No versions is involved

Another strange thing is that if I use a HttpUserPoolAuthorizer (JWT for Cognito), *that* authorizer works OK